# No error message on "The PowerShell script failed to execute", Service Fabric app upgrade from VS15

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I used to be able to do upgrade, and it suddenly wont work, not to cloud and not locally.

And there is no error message, so I have no clue what to do.

Publishing a new application works fine.

There seems to be something corrupt with the solution, but I have no idea where I should be looking for this. 
In a brand new project, publishing and upgrading a stateful service from template, works without problem.

Things I have done:

- Cleaned solution.
- Rebuilt solution.
- Deleted Debug folders in bin and obj folders.
- Restarted Visual Studio.
- Cleared MEF Component Cache.
- Restarted machine.
- Restarted cluster.

The brand new project is deployed to same cluster and upgrade it is working, so I have not deleted the cluster to deploy a new one.

There is no error being thrown so enclosing the script in a try catch seems pointless.
What else can I do here, what can I do to try find out what is going wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it might be a bug. It is reported here:

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/240

Summary: When deployed with compression, further upgrades require config version bump, even though config has not changed.

Comment: I'll wait with accepting this as answer until this is confirmed by SF team.